# How to calculate compound rate for period with varying rate?

Tags: statistics

What I mean is, for instance, let's say I have a daily rate like this:

​

| Day | Rate |
| --- | --- |
| Day 1 | 0.15 |
| Day 2 | 0.35 |
| [...] | [...] |
| Day 30 | 0.02 |
| Day 31 | 0.07 |

​

How do I calculate the total rate for the month for example?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what's the context? Does the principal compound at the end of each day? So for example, if you start with $100$ at the beginning of day 1, you have $115$ at the beginning of day 2 (assuming your rate of $0.15$ represents $15\%$, and not $0.15\%$), does the $0.35$ rate for day 2 apply to just the initial $100$, or to the total $115$? Give us more details or we don't know how to help.

Comment: It's a compound interest rate, but the rate changes daily, so yes, the 0.35% would apply to 115 in your example. I've tried calculating it as: (1 + daily rate #1) * (1 + daily rate #2) * (1 + daily rate #3) * [...] * (1 + daily rate #n), but it was wrong. My goal is to calculate the total rate for a set period of time (in months or years) without having to know the investment value, so I could apply just the total rate for a set period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm dumb and my initial solution wasn't working because the Excel formula was one cell off.

I calculated it by doing:

> Total rate of period with **n** days = (1 + daily rate #1) * (1 + daily rate #2) * (1 + daily
> rate #3) * [...] * (1 + daily rate #n)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).